# TexStudio save default settings

Tags: texstudio, texmaker

I'm working on macOS Monterey (version 12.3) and just did a fresh install of TexStudio (version 4.2.3). When I try to change some editor settings (e.g., the color scheme) I get the following message upon closing the program:

```
Storing session information into /Users/MyName/.config/texstudio/lastSession.txss2 failed. File exists but is not writeable.
```

If I then reopen TexStudio, the visual styling is all default, so my changes did not take. When I check this directory in Terminal I see that /.config doesn't even contain a texstudio directory.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What are the permissions on `~/.config`? Does manully creating `~/.config/texstudio` help at all?

Comment: "system" has read & write permissions, and while the ~/.config/texstudio directory did not originally exist, after I created that directory I continue to get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue with texstudio.
I resolved this problem by manually entering the .config folder and creating a new folder named "texstudio". After doing so, texstudio was able to save changed settings again.
In order to access this folder on a mac use the shortcut cmd + shift + g, then access the path ~/.config.